# Error connecting to cloud spanner: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I am trying to get list of databases for my instance in cloud spanner

```
Spanner spannerClient=SpannerOptions.newBuilder().build().getService();
InstanceAdminClient instanceAdminClient = spannerClient.getInstanceAdminClient();
            Page<Database> databasePage = instanceAdminClient.getInstance(instanceID).listDatabases();
            for (Database database : databasePage.getValues()) {
                String databaseName = database.getId().getDatabase();
                log.info("Database-->"+databaseName);
            }
```

The code works fine in my local environment but gets blocked when I try to run the same code in a yarn container. I got the below log from threaddump

```
Thread 10275: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=215 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(int, long) @bci=139, line=1037 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(int, long) @bci=25, line=1328 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=10, line=277 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerImpl.backoffSleep(io.grpc.Context, long) @bci=67, line=200 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerImpl.backoffSleep(io.grpc.Context, com.shaded.scanner.google.api.client.util.BackOff) @bci=5, line=170 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerImpl.runWithRetries(java.util.concurrent.Callable) @bci=105, line=238 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerImpl$InstanceAdminClientImpl.getInstance(java.lang.String) @bci=25, line=660 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.test.spannerscanner.utils.GoogleSpannerManager.execute() @bci=289, line=93 (Interpreted frame)
```

I am not able to figure out why the connection is getting blocked in the yarn container but working fine in local. Upon further debugging I found out that the code is getting blocked due to SpannerException thrown in runWithRetries method in SpannerImpl class. The code is catching the exception and retyring after some backoff and thus getting blocked. The SpannerException has the following message :

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
```

Any help or suggestions on why this exception is being thrown in the yarn  container is greatly appreciated. I am using cloud spanner 0.52-beta version.

Comment: I was able to figure out the issue. It was getting blocked due to the ssl certificates not present in the truststore.jks file we were using.